# Distribute key to all values in pyspark rdd

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have an rdd of the form:

```
[(1111, [(0, 174, 12.44, 3.125, u'c29'), (0, 175, 12.48, 6.125, u'c59')], 2222, [(0, 178, 19.41, 2.165, u'c79'), (0, 171, 18.41, 3.125, u'c41')]]
```

how can I flatten the intermediary list and obtain the rdd as a list of tuples, where each tuple contains the corresponding key and its values, like so:

```
[(1111, 0, 174, 12.44, 3.125, u'c29'), (1111, 0, 175, 12.48, 6.125, u'c59'), (2222, 0, 178, 19.41, 2.165, u'c79'), (2222, 0, 171, 18.41, 3.125, u'c41')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `flatMap`:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(x[0], ) + y for y in x[1]])
```